# Package in LaTeX that will use SAS font?

Tags: fonts

I was hoping to find a package that would give me output in the SAS font, but haven't been able to find one.  Any ideas?  Cheers.

Comment: May be you need [ctan search](http://www.ctan.org/search) with `SAS` leads [SASnRdisplay](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sasnrdisplay/SASnRdisplay.pdf) and [statrep](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/statrep/statrep.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official name of the SAS font is
SAS monospace Bold

according to the file associations in this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\SASHome\ReportFontsforClients\9.3\SystemFonts\backup
```

sasmono.ttf
and
sasmonob.ttf
are of type: TrueType Font file

google truetype font sas monospace bold returns this link:

http://www.ufonts.com/fonts/sas-monospace-bold.html

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.